# How to skip step in bot framework Waterfall BeginDialog Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am having an Waterfall dialog with 3 steps.
step 1 - expects a input from user
step 2 - process the input and displays a card
step 3 - end dialog

When i use BeginDialog i am able to trigger the waterfall dialog. But i want trigger the same dialog by skiping the step 1 as i have input to pass via code.

I tried to use this but not successful. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/skipstepfunction?view=botbuilder-ts-latest

```
await dc.beginDialog(HELP);
```

I expect that the dialog to be modular and so that i can call them by skipping any steps or follow the regular flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution .

Based on some condition in step 1 we can trigger the step.next()

```
step.next()
```